# How do I make my charts full screen in flexdashboards?

Tags: r, plotly, flexdashboard

[image]

I have these two charts. They are filling up part of the screen.

How do I make them fill the whole screen?

I have it set up with this config code

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---
```

And then the charts are defined with this setup

```
Overview
=====================================  

Column 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

    chart

Column 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

    chart
```

Comment: If you're using {ggplot2}, you'll have to tinker with the size within each chunk. As RStudio mentions here, "Charts based on htmlwidgets are ideal for use with flexdashboard because they can dynamically re-size themselves, so will nearly always fit perfectly within the bounds of their flexdashboard containers." https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/using.html#sizing

Comment: I'm using plotly for my charts

Comment: You could try this:  ` Column {style = "data-width: 50%;"} `

Answer (score 0):

You can put your plotly object inside the plotly function renderPlotly(). This dynamicalle resizes the graph to the page size. See and example how I used it in this blog post:
https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/shiny-dashboards-with-flexdashboard-e66aaafac1f2